# Server Error in '/' Application asp web api

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am working on ASP web api with angularjs. I want to load index.html as the default page. But whenever '/' route is entered, 404 resource not found error is thrown. Instead when I enter the URL '/index.html' page can be viewed. I want to load index.html page when '/' route is entered.
 RouteConfig.cs file is as follows -  `

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );`  

app.js file - `$routeProvider.when('/', { template: '<div></div>', controller: '' })`
```

Answer (score 0):

**Adding the following line before `routes.MapRoute` might help you**

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

Comment: added but still the same. 404 resource not found.